# Determine if a 4-tuple exists

Tags: problem-solving, combinatorial-game-theory

Starting with 2,0,0,3, we construct the sequence 2,0,0,3,5,8,6,..., where each new digit is the mod10 sum of the preceding four terms. Will the 4-tuple 0,4,0,7 ever occur?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Since this problem is from a Working Backwards chapter, I have tried working with the desired four tuple and working backwards to determine other previous integers with no contradiction apparent. Thus, I am greatly confused.

Comment: Well, you can always keep constructing the original sequence until you repeat something, but I think a easier way would be to determine some invariant.

Maybe instead of mod $10$ you can try a smaller number?

Comment: I just wrote a program and my observation is that: The 4 tuple sequence repeats with the length of 1560. The 1st number is 2003, and 1560th number is 1200. You can see that 1561th number is again 2003. 0407 is the 1556th number. You can trace in the reverse order and can see it, that is, 2003 - 1200 - 7120 - 0712- 4071 - 0407.

Comment: So my suggestion is that if we can somehow prove that the sequence will come back to 2003, then it is easy to prove that 0407 will show up as well.

Comment: On the other hand, the rest of four digit numbers (there are 8440 of them) never shows up. I changed the seed to $2004$ (that didn't show up in the original loop) and I got 312 tuples cycling. So I guess that this sequence may be always come back to the seed (initial tuple). It would be interesting to see if somebody can prove it.

Comment: I also posted. Please check my sequence..

Answer (score 7):

> [Lemma] The sequence will come back to the original tuple (in this case, 2003).

(Proof)

Choosing the next number is always deterministic. At the same time, identifying the previous number is also deterministic. As there are finite set of 4 digit numbers, at some point the sequence will run out. And then it will have to cycle. The initial number should be inside that cycle, as otherwise it would mean that the cycle has a branch (or a junction) that is not possible as the backward sequence is also deterministic.

$$\\$$

So, 2003 will show up 2nd time (and actually over and over again). For 2003 to show up the below sequence should happen:

$$0-4-0-7-1-2-0-0-3$$

Therefore, 0407 will show up.

Comment: The process is invertible (given four numbers, we can determine the previous as well as the next); therefore, the first time it repeats, we must come back to the original.  And it must repeat, since there are only finitely many possible 4-tuples.

Comment: If your program did this, then I must be wrong.

Comment: @fleabood, sorry about that. You were competing with a program. :-)

Comment: @Ted, But how can you say that the reverse sequence will come to the original number?

Comment: @Ted, for example, what I was thinking is that the cycle might be like (calling the initial tuple as $A$) $A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-C-D-E-F-G-H-C-D-E-F-G-H-...$

Comment: Suppose the 4-tuples we get are $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$.  At some point, two of them repeat, say $a_i = a_j$.  We may assume this is the first repeat we encounter.  If $i = 0$, then we have come back to the original.  If $i > 0$, then we have $a_{i-1} = a_{j-1}$ (because the process is invertible), so we have an earlier repeat, contradiction.

Comment: @Ted, my bad. Yes you are right. The sequence is fully deterministic so it should come back.

Comment: As all sequences are backtrackable and there is a maximum of 10,000 4 tuples it *must* repeat and before the repetition it *must* previously be 0,4,0,7,1

Comment: Good observations, but I am having trouble putting it all together. Could someone please explain the proof of why the desired 4-tuple occurs?

Comment: I rephrased everything. Please see if it helps.

Comment: Are you saying the the sequence 0 4 0 7 1 2 0 0 3, by working backwards will start with 2 0 0 3? So this will happen: 2 0 0 3,...,0 4 0 7 1 2 0 0 3 ?

Comment: I am just not convinced that we are guaranteed that 2003 will repeat and to know how many times it will.

Comment: Yes, that's right. 2003 will happen again, which means 0407 should happen too.

Comment: Okay, that's the key. I understand you're not convinced that 2003 will happen again. But are you convinced that the sequence will begin to cyclic in the end?

Comment: No please explain, if you could, why it would cycle in the end.

Comment: Okay, if it doesn't cycle, then there must be infinitely many possible tuples. But it is not possible. So it should be cycling. You may say "can it just keep going around without cycling", right?

Comment: Is there any initial 4-tuple that generates all possible 4-tuples (sort of like a de Bruijn sequence)?

Comment: @marty I don't think so, because there are already a couple of known initial tuples that generate partial cyclic sequences. If there exists a tuple that would generate all possible tuples then it would violate the lemma. These cyclic sequences should be mutually isolated.

Comment: @Analysis15 Let $A$ be the operation by which we go from one tuple to the next, e.g. $A(4, 0, 7, 1) = (2, 0, 0, 3)$. We know $A$ is invertible, call its inverse $A^{-1}$, that is, $A^{-1}(2, 0, 0, 3)  = (4, 0, 7, 1)$. Let $x_0=(2, 0, 0, 3)$, then we're looking at the sequence $A^nx_0$. Since there are only finitely many possible tuples, we must have $A^nx_0=A^mx_0$ for $m$ and some $n>m$. But then $A^{n-m}x_0=x_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, from any x, y, z, w  we can determine the previous term and there is no choice for variation.  (As A + x +y + z = w has only one answer.)

As there are only finitely many 4-tuples the sequence must eventually repeat.

2,0,0,3 must come from

1,2,0,0 which must come from

7,1,2,0 which must come from

0,7,1,2 which must come from

4,0,7,1 which must come from

0, 4, 0,7.

Thus the sequence must repeat and 0,4,0,7 will appear near the very end of the cycle.